# Groovy Spring Contract DLS turns string into JSON

Tags: java, spring-boot, groovy, spring-cloud

I have the following contract generating script:

```
VALID_JSON_STRING = '{}'
[
        Contract.make {
            name("insertSomething_ShouldReturnHttp200")
            description("POST should do sth")
            request {
                method 'POST'
                url REQUEST_URL
                body(
                        value: VALID_JSON_STRING
                )
                headers {
                    contentType(applicationJson())
                }
            }
            response {
                status 200
                headers {  contentType(applicationJson()) } }
        }
]
```

But it gets compiled to:

```
@Test
public void insertSomething_ShouldReturnHttp200() throws Exception {
    // given:
        MockMvcRequestSpecification request = given()
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .body("{\"value\":{}}");

    // when:
        ResponseOptions response = given().spec(request)
                .post("...");

    // then:
        assertThat(response.statusCode()).isEqualTo(200);
        assertThat(response.header("Content-Type")).matches("application/json.*");
}
```

Notice the `.body("{\"value\":{}}");` here.

Instead it should be `.body("{\"value\":\"{}\"}");`. It should not convert the JSON-string to an actual JSON. How do I prevent this?

> EDIT: It was labeled as a bug now: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-contract/issues/652

Comment: What is your API endpoint's actual contract at Controller, are writing cloud-contract for empty body?

Comment: @YogendraMishra No, then I would return a 204 code without a body. I am returning a body with a property that contains a JSON-string. The use-case for that is mocking a NoSQL database in SQL until we can move to an actual NoSQL one.